# jquery ui accordions within tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I’ve run into a problem using accordions within tabs, the initially inactive accordions do not render their content correctly when their tab is selected. 
Reading around I see the reason for this is that the inactive tabs have display:none initially, so the height of the divs within the accordion do not get calculated correctly. None of the suggested solutions work for me.
Have has anyone overcome this or have a work around?

Here's some example code of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" media="screen" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.js'></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $("#accordion1").accordion();
    $("#accordion2").accordion(); 
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
   <div id="main" class="round roundB">

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a> </li>      
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a> </li>
  </ul>

<div id="tab1">
  <div id="accordion1">
 <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
 <div>
  <p>
  TAB 1 Accordion 1
  </p>
 </div>
 <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
 <div>
  <p>
  TAB 1 Accordion 2
  </p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tab2">
  <div id="accordion2">
 <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
 <div>
  <p>
  TAB 2 Accordion 1
  </p>
 </div>
 <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
 <div>
  <p>
  TAB 2 Accordion 2
  </p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I had the same problem before.
The solution is: You must active accordion before tabs.

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Maybe you need left align.

```
.ui-accordion-header{
  text-align: left;
}
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than the solution I came up with!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I was having so much trouble trying to work this issue around that I didn't realized the solution could be this easy. Thanks again.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Excellent solution.

Comment: Gd bless you! LOL. This saved me so much time.

Answer (score 7):

After reading the stated problem, it was my impression that a problem I have run into was of a similar nature.  Using the accordion functionality within a tab was forcing my accordion content to contain a scrollbar, a feature I did not want.

For some reason or another, the current solution provided did not work for me.

The solution I found was to overwrite the default accordion setting of autoHeight (default of true, overwrite to false)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false
});
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been tearing my hair out all day trying to solve this. The "accepted answer" above did not help - but this fixed it!

Comment: +1, if a small scrollbar appears this solution is for you. thanks

Comment: Still preventing hair loss in 2018!!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize accordion when you activate tab:

sample:

```
$('.selector').bind('tabsadd', function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

your sample:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#tabs').bind('tabshow', function(event, ui) {
        $("#accordion1").accordion();
        $("#accordion2").accordion(); 
    });

  });
  </script>
```

Maybe that you will need to initialize every accordion special for each tab.

Or use latest UI lib:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/base2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/bgiframe/jquery.bgiframe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $("#"+ui.panel.id+" .accordians:first").accordion();
        }
    });
```

This worked when using ajax html with tabs.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. For me, the trick was to change from using unique div IDs for each accordion to a single class identification for all accordions. That is, change: `<div id="accordion1>, <div id="accordion2>,`etc... to`<div class="accordion">` within each of the tabs.

You may also need to add to your $(document).ready function

> ```
> $(".accordion").accordion({
>       autoHeight: false
>   });
>
>   $('#tabs').tabs();
>   $('#tabs').bind('tabshow', function(event, ui) {
>       $(".accordion").accordion("resize");
>       });
> ```

So the format would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" media="screen" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.js'></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $(".accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false
      });

      $('#tabs').tabs();
      $('#tabs').bind('tabshow', function(event, ui) {
          $(".accordion").accordion("resize");
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Folders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Decks</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class='accordion'>
            <h3>Header 1</h3>
            <div</div>  
            <h3>Header 2</h3>
            <div></div> 
            <h3>Header 3</h3>
            <div><</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class='accordion'>
            <h3>Header 4</h3>
            <div</div>  
            <h3>Header 5</h3>
            <div></div> 
            <h3>Header 6</h3>
            <div><</div> 
        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
        <div class='accordion'>
            <h3>Header 7</h3>
            <div</div>  
            <h3>Header 8</h3>
            <div></div> 
            <h3>Header 9</h3>
            <div><</div> 
        </div>  
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5601

.ui-helper-clearfix { display:block; min-width: 0; overflow: hidden; }

Answer (score -1):

just read carefully http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#
there is an answer. it's simpliest way