# jQuery Accordion and Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to get a jQueryUI accordion working inside jQueryUI tabs. I've read of people having problems and have found several posts which have reported success from initializing the accordion inside the tabs' 'show' event, but when I try this I just get what looks like two half-styled tab headers and no accordion functionality. I have the following in my page load event:

```
$().ready(function() {  
   tabs = $('.jqTabsStandard').tabs({
        show: function(ev, ui) {
            $('.ingredientsAccordion').accordion({
              autoHeight: true,
                header: 'h3 a'
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

The page is [here](http://www.chickenping.com/myrecipes.aspx) - click the edit (pencil) button for a recipe, then click the ingredients tab.

Comment: does the accordion work if its not in the tab ? also can you give just the html for the tabs and accordion

Comment: Please review:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542161/jquery-ui-accordions-within-tabs/6796264#6796264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was as simple as changing the order in which the UI is loaded. First initialize the accordion, the the tabs, that way the accordion has height and is not invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I check it with developer tools in Chrome: your accordion data containers is ok but has 1px height. That's why you see almost nothing. Try to change height of tabs container, because when accordion initiates on tab that fit content then accordion actually has no space for sliding. I am sorry for bad english :)

Comment: But the container doesn't have an explicit height, it should be the available tab height, but as the second tab (with the accordion) is hidden when the page loads, it's invisible.