# Why does this jQuery UI Accordion (nested inside a Tabs object) only work for the first of the 3 Tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

I put an accordion inside each of the 3 Tab panes.

But only the accordion on the first Tab works when you click on its section headings.

http://jsfiddle.net/JmdCa/

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui accordions within tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542161/jquery-ui-accordions-within-tabs)

Answer (score 1):

This has the answer for you: [jquery ui accordions within tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1542161/605907)